# Error while using await to add elements into database C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, async-await

Sample code:

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var context = new DBContext())
        {
            await context.Objects.Add(new Level
            {  
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Name 1"
            });
        }
}
```

Creates error:

```
Objects does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Objects' could be found.
```

It's TPH database, Objects is class at the top of hierarchy.

I have no idea how to fix it, i'm not sure why it doesn't work here. I have heard it can be issue with using older C# (i don't use 8.0 because i'm unable to upgrade it).

Comment: [`DbSet<T>.Add(T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.add?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) does **not** return a `Task`. If you want to persist what you have added to the `DbSet<T>` then call `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync` and await the resulting `Task` that this call returns.

Comment: `i'm not sure why it doesn't work here` it wont, there's no task returned as mentioned already. Looking at that code, there's honestly no reason to even try and await it.

Comment: Missing a closing `)` in `Add(new Level`

Comment: @Igor It's not the constructor `(` that's missing, it's the close for `Add`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding doesn't do any heavyweight operations. It simply adds the object to the in-memory context, not the database. Therefore there is no point (or opportunity) to do it asynchronously.

Data is sent to the database only when you do

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

so you can do

```
await context.SaveChangesAsync()
```

at that point.